# PHP does return from file_get_contents when using url, but not when url is loaded from array

Tags: php, arrays, image, url, load

I'm trying to return image from URL (from Reddit). The URLs are stored in array $out:

```
Array ( 
[0] => https://preview.redd.it/pvloz4h9whp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=983c6b25740ed0389f8077e25d9ade75ae967b81 
[1] => https://preview.redd.it/15syi021vhp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=b2bff216f7164084026ad25a11bc4a07f8f88e32 
[2] => https://preview.redd.it/rz8xy4csrhp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=8a1b4d5ac04958399a184dcbc2045bcb33b559a1 
)
```

When I put get_file_contents from original url it works and returns image.

```
$image = file_get_contents('https://preview.redd.it/pvloz4h9whp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=983c6b25740ed0389f8077e25d9ade75ae967b81');

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $image;
```

But when I get the URL from array it returns blank page.

```
$image = file_get_contents($out[0]);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $image;
```

I get $out by this rather unclear mess:

```
$posts = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.reddit.com/r/creepyasterisks/new.json?sort=new&limit=5', true), true)['data']['children'];
$out = array();
foreach($posts as $post){
  $post = json_encode($post, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  $post = json_decode($post);
  $post = $post->data->preview->images;
  $post = json_encode($post, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  $post = substr($post, 1, -1);
  $post = json_decode($post);
  $post = $post->resolutions[1]->url;
  array_push($out, $post);
}
print_r($out);
```

$posts from Reddit API looks something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [kind] => t3 [data] => Array ( [approved_at_utc] => [subreddit] => creepyasterisks [selftext] => [author_fullname] => t2_3720n0v6 [saved] => [mod_reason_title] => [gilded] => 0 [clicked] => [title] => I censored the name this time do this is going to get posted right [link_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [subreddit_name_prefixed] => r/creepyasterisks [hidden] => [pwls] => 1 [link_flair_css_class] => [downs] => 0 [thumbnail_height] => 140 [hide_score] => 1 [name] => t3_b833sa [quarantine] => [link_flair_text_color] => dark [author_flair_background_color] => [subreddit_type] => public [ups] => 2 [domain] => i.redd.it [media_embed] => Array ( ) [thumbnail_width] => 140 [author_flair_template_id] => [is_original_content] => [user_reports] => Array ( ) [secure_media] => [is_reddit_media_domain] => 1 [is_meta] => [category] => [secure_media_embed] => Array ( ) [link_flair_text] => [can_mod_post] => [score] => 2 [approved_by] => [thumbnail] => https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/S0nYyNiSnFxxfdkGufR4dEWnYz9mGdxvUrvA71WK7wI.jpg [edited] => [author_flair_css_class] => [author_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [gildings] => Array ( [gid_1] => 0 [gid_2] => 0 [gid_3] => 0 ) [post_hint] => image [content_categories] => [is_self] => [mod_note] => [created] => 1554128966 [link_flair_type] => text [wls] => 1 [banned_by] => [author_flair_type] => text [contest_mode] => [selftext_html] => [likes] => [suggested_sort] => confidence [banned_at_utc] => [view_count] => [archived] => [no_follow] => 1 [is_crosspostable] => [pinned] => [over_18] => [preview] => Array ( [images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [source] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/5hi03detxnp21.jpg?auto=webp&s=f8ceec3fb866d45b46787e5762abb8b28dba6569 [width] => 640 [height] => 1136 ) [resolutions] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/5hi03detxnp21.jpg?width=108&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=7be41b205ae3871844fae47f0112d04393c94cf7 [width] => 108 [height] => 191 ) [1] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/5hi03detxnp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=72a10a1dbb6bc5a8839e7660ce0ae41eb47b0adf [width] => 216 [height] => 383 ) [2] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/5hi03detxnp21.jpg?width=320&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=7c6abe323b889580f53d911c2ff758501adb8dff [width] => 320 [height] => 568 ) [3] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/5hi03detxnp21.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=8c9cb679cb2c03f851e7f493cc5bb6534e3405ac [width] => 640 [height] => 1136 ) ) [variants] => Array ( ) [id] => k1XO8pgSDbyGclzeD-eC7PInxsLmxj_uXpR24IhdIoA ) ) [enabled] => 1 ) [media_only] => [can_gild] => [spoiler] => [locked] => [author_flair_text] => [visited] => [num_reports] => [distinguished] => [subreddit_id] => t5_3hmzi [mod_reason_by] => [removal_reason] => [link_flair_background_color] => [id] => b833sa [is_robot_indexable] => 1 [report_reasons] => [author] => cannonballcruise [num_crossposts] => 0 [num_comments] => 2 [send_replies] => 1 [whitelist_status] => house_only [mod_reports] => Array ( ) [author_patreon_flair] => [author_flair_text_color] => [permalink] => /r/creepyasterisks/comments/b833sa/i_censored_the_name_this_time_do_this_is_going_to/ [parent_whitelist_status] => house_only [stickied] => [url] => https://i.redd.it/5hi03detxnp21.jpg [subreddit_subscribers] => 346546 [created_utc] => 1554128966 [media] => [is_video] => ) ) [1] => Array ( [kind] => t3 [data] => Array ( [approved_at_utc] => [subreddit] => creepyasterisks [selftext] => [author_fullname] => t2_2xaiw3tb [saved] => [mod_reason_title] => [gilded] => 0 [clicked] => [title] => Man gets the big suck [link_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [subreddit_name_prefixed] => r/creepyasterisks [hidden] => [pwls] => 1 [link_flair_css_class] => [downs] => 0 [thumbnail_height] => 140 [hide_score] => 1 [name] => t3_b82e1o [quarantine] => [link_flair_text_color] => dark [author_flair_background_color] => [subreddit_type] => public [ups] => 23 [domain] => i.redd.it [media_embed] => Array ( ) [thumbnail_width] => 140 [author_flair_template_id] => [is_original_content] => [user_reports] => Array ( ) [secure_media] => [is_reddit_media_domain] => 1 [is_meta] => [category] => [secure_media_embed] => Array ( ) [link_flair_text] => [can_mod_post] => [score] => 23 [approved_by] => [thumbnail] => https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/3SprUxXkDoTgDDaeHdzmFJpO6NtQxfRRZqCKeCQwG5s.jpg [edited] => [author_flair_css_class] => [author_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [gildings] => Array ( [gid_1] => 0 [gid_2] => 0 [gid_3] => 0 ) [post_hint] => image [content_categories] => [is_self] => [mod_note] => [crosspost_parent_list] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [approved_at_utc] => [subreddit] => Nicegirls [selftext] => [author_fullname] => t2_4g5h5g3 [saved] => [mod_reason_title] => [gilded] => 0 [clicked] => [title] => Kirby is on Tinder. [link_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [subreddit_name_prefixed] => r/Nicegirls [hidden] => [pwls] => 6 [link_flair_css_class] => [downs] => 0 [thumbnail_height] => 140 [hide_score] => [name] => t3_b7qxvt [quarantine] => [link_flair_text_color] => dark [author_flair_background_color] => [subreddit_type] => public [ups] => 745 [domain] => i.redd.it [media_embed] => Array ( ) [thumbnail_width] => 140 [author_flair_template_id] => [is_original_content] => [user_reports] => Array ( ) [secure_media] => [is_reddit_media_domain] => 1 [is_meta] => [category] => [secure_media_embed] => Array ( ) [link_flair_text] => [can_mod_post] => [score] => 745 [approved_by] => [thumbnail] => https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/3SprUxXkDoTgDDaeHdzmFJpO6NtQxfRRZqCKeCQwG5s.jpg [edited] => [author_flair_css_class] => [author_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [gildings] => Array ( [gid_1] => 0 [gid_2] => 0 [gid_3] => 0 ) [post_hint] => image [content_categories] => [is_self] => [mod_note] => [created] => 1554056995 [link_flair_type] => text [wls] => 6 [banned_by] => [author_flair_type] => text [contest_mode] => [selftext_html] => [likes] => [suggested_sort] => [banned_at_utc] => [view_count] => [archived] => [no_follow] => [is_crosspostable] => [pinned] => [over_18] => [preview] => Array ( [images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [source] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg?auto=webp&s=fefd6ec478e645c0b23f798ff086a41b015c73e7 [width] => 750 [height] => 1334 ) [resolutions] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg?width=108&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=0e5c898c65ade86239bb5d7d42df1acbee11e055 [width] => 108 [height] => 192 ) [1] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=3f5153111efc075185a8bddda281a28cb7a40bb5 [width] => 216 [height] => 384 ) [2] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg?width=320&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=7948b7a1e738f61100fd6491bb8ae81afef6a9ac [width] => 320 [height] => 569 ) [3] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=ff138bc96ec284c91a66a7f9b5592e960f090e86 [width] => 640 [height] => 1138 ) ) [variants] => Array ( ) [id] => f3wRd5KEq_WXkRcllpvEGTR-f9oretQAQ3Ur1wgvuq4 ) ) [enabled] => 1 ) [media_only] => [can_gild] => [spoiler] => [locked] => [author_flair_text] => [visited] => [num_reports] => [distinguished] => [subreddit_id] => t5_2svqn [mod_reason_by] => [removal_reason] => [link_flair_background_color] => [id] => b7qxvt [is_robot_indexable] => 1 [report_reasons] => [author] => joeclark5 [num_crossposts] => 3 [num_comments] => 52 [send_replies] => 1 [whitelist_status] => all_ads [mod_reports] => Array ( ) [author_patreon_flair] => [author_flair_text_color] => [permalink] => /r/Nicegirls/comments/b7qxvt/kirby_is_on_tinder/ [parent_whitelist_status] => all_ads [stickied] => [url] => https://i.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg [subreddit_subscribers] => 440382 [created_utc] => 1554056995 [media] => [is_video] => ) ) [created] => 1554125308 [link_flair_type] => text [wls] => 1 [banned_by] => [author_flair_type] => text [contest_mode] => [selftext_html] => [likes] => [suggested_sort] => confidence [banned_at_utc] => [view_count] => [archived] => [no_follow] => [is_crosspostable] => [pinned] => [over_18] => [preview] => Array ( [images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [source] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg?auto=webp&s=fefd6ec478e645c0b23f798ff086a41b015c73e7 [width] => 750 [height] => 1334 ) [resolutions] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg?width=108&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=0e5c898c65ade86239bb5d7d42df1acbee11e055 [width] => 108 [height] => 192 ) [1] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=3f5153111efc075185a8bddda281a28cb7a40bb5 [width] => 216 [height] => 384 ) [2] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg?width=320&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=7948b7a1e738f61100fd6491bb8ae81afef6a9ac [width] => 320 [height] => 569 ) [3] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=ff138bc96ec284c91a66a7f9b5592e960f090e86 [width] => 640 [height] => 1138 ) ) [variants] => Array ( ) [id] => f3wRd5KEq_WXkRcllpvEGTR-f9oretQAQ3Ur1wgvuq4 ) ) [enabled] => 1 ) [media_only] => [can_gild] => [spoiler] => [locked] => [author_flair_text] => [visited] => [num_reports] => [distinguished] => [subreddit_id] => t5_3hmzi [mod_reason_by] => [removal_reason] => [link_flair_background_color] => [id] => b82e1o [is_robot_indexable] => 1 [report_reasons] => [author] => bwagner777 [num_crossposts] => 0 [num_comments] => 10 [send_replies] => [whitelist_status] => house_only [mod_reports] => Array ( ) [author_patreon_flair] => [crosspost_parent] => t3_b7qxvt [author_flair_text_color] => [permalink] => /r/creepyasterisks/comments/b82e1o/man_gets_the_big_suck/ [parent_whitelist_status] => house_only [stickied] => [url] => https://i.redd.it/qy4tymdrzhp21.jpg [subreddit_subscribers] => 346546 [created_utc] => 1554125308 [media] => [is_video] => ) ) [2] => Array ( [kind] => t3 [data] => Array ( [approved_at_utc] => [subreddit] => creepyasterisks [selftext] => [author_fullname] => t2_8f6k5d [saved] => [mod_reason_title] => [gilded] => 0 [clicked] => [title] => I want to think this was a joke... [link_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [subreddit_name_prefixed] => r/creepyasterisks [hidden] => [pwls] => 1 [link_flair_css_class] => [downs] => 0 [thumbnail_height] => 140 [hide_score] => [name] => t3_b7wdp4 [quarantine] => [link_flair_text_color] => dark [author_flair_background_color] => [subreddit_type] => public [ups] => 1901 [domain] => i.redd.it [media_embed] => Array ( ) [thumbnail_width] => 140 [author_flair_template_id] => 20d5a2d8-1cc9-11e8-80d7-0e10a7179ac4 [is_original_content] => [user_reports] => Array ( ) [secure_media] => [is_reddit_media_domain] => 1 [is_meta] => [category] => [secure_media_embed] => Array ( ) [link_flair_text] => [can_mod_post] => [score] => 1901 [approved_by] => [thumbnail] => https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/t4v_j1GLBeRlQQ7SghEGJWPQa1t03WXoO4FVE9ORWMM.jpg [edited] => [author_flair_css_class] => [author_flair_richtext] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [e] => text [t] => Trying my best not to be the subject of a post here ) ) [gildings] => Array ( [gid_1] => 0 [gid_2] => 0 [gid_3] => 0 ) [post_hint] => image [content_categories] => [is_self] => [mod_note] => [created] => 1554087031 [link_flair_type] => text [wls] => 1 [banned_by] => [author_flair_type] => richtext [contest_mode] => [selftext_html] => [likes] => [suggested_sort] => confidence [banned_at_utc] => [view_count] => [archived] => [no_follow] => [is_crosspostable] => [pinned] => [over_18] => [preview] => Array ( [images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [source] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/m1dw0aw1hkp21.jpg?auto=webp&s=d977ab60d757e760ffbe4365d9dc33ebf6e027a2 [width] => 1200 [height] => 3911 ) [resolutions] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/m1dw0aw1hkp21.jpg?width=108&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=a37379f910a5ad2061fe6d23794a4e59fd87af06 [width] => 108 [height] => 216 ) [1] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/m1dw0aw1hkp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=d84ef2bc47c953a49a001dccdb99ce115eb8efde [width] => 216 [height] => 432 ) [2] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/m1dw0aw1hkp21.jpg?width=320&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=7415db81c7139c95779560eb62f85b5488565850 [width] => 320 [height] => 640 ) [3] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/m1dw0aw1hkp21.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=3f629a39d3ca7cf540bd0129cdbabeb48cbe2860 [width] => 640 [height] => 1280 ) [4] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/m1dw0aw1hkp21.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=1930a72edff6032b494e2fc5bc3890842dd793f7 [width] => 960 [height] => 1920 ) [5] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/m1dw0aw1hkp21.jpg?width=1080&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=09230605994a21b2d57b63089dc0f7360a671e61 [width] => 1080 [height] => 2160 ) ) [variants] => Array ( ) [id] => MoY-W4zN-Wy3FHOMicingDsrDgfFLadfDkd-HEOPr1A ) ) [enabled] => 1 ) [media_only] => [can_gild] => [spoiler] => [locked] => [author_flair_text] => Trying my best not to be the subject of a post here [visited] => [num_reports] => [distinguished] => [subreddit_id] => t5_3hmzi [mod_reason_by] => [removal_reason] => [link_flair_background_color] => [id] => b7wdp4 [is_robot_indexable] => 1 [report_reasons] => [author] => PhenomenalPancake [num_crossposts] => 2 [num_comments] => 125 [send_replies] => 1 [whitelist_status] => house_only [mod_reports] => Array ( ) [author_patreon_flair] => [author_flair_text_color] => dark [permalink] => /r/creepyasterisks/comments/b7wdp4/i_want_to_think_this_was_a_joke/ [parent_whitelist_status] => house_only [stickied] => [url] => https://i.redd.it/m1dw0aw1hkp21.jpg [subreddit_subscribers] => 346546 [created_utc] => 1554087031 [media] => [is_video] => ) ) [3] => Array ( [kind] => t3 [data] => Array ( [approved_at_utc] => [subreddit] => creepyasterisks [selftext] => [author_fullname] => t2_s7j4f [saved] => [mod_reason_title] => [gilded] => 0 [clicked] => [title] => Something that I thought my friend would never do... [link_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [subreddit_name_prefixed] => r/creepyasterisks [hidden] => [pwls] => 1 [link_flair_css_class] => [downs] => 0 [thumbnail_height] => 118 [hide_score] => [name] => t3_b7tgk3 [quarantine] => [link_flair_text_color] => dark [author_flair_background_color] => [subreddit_type] => public [ups] => 996 [domain] => i.redd.it [media_embed] => Array ( ) [thumbnail_width] => 140 [author_flair_template_id] => [is_original_content] => [user_reports] => Array ( ) [secure_media] => [is_reddit_media_domain] => 1 [is_meta] => [category] => [secure_media_embed] => Array ( ) [link_flair_text] => [can_mod_post] => [score] => 996 [approved_by] => [thumbnail] => https://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/s3Jdcv0Ijm3QQqH5L_qjqe8Il9MAWBFSVtXhKBp57L4.jpg [edited] => [author_flair_css_class] => [author_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [gildings] => Array ( [gid_1] => 0 [gid_2] => 0 [gid_3] => 0 ) [post_hint] => image [content_categories] => [is_self] => [mod_note] => [created] => 1554070070 [link_flair_type] => text [wls] => 1 [banned_by] => [author_flair_type] => text [contest_mode] => [selftext_html] => [likes] => [suggested_sort] => confidence [banned_at_utc] => [view_count] => [archived] => [no_follow] => [is_crosspostable] => [pinned] => [over_18] => [preview] => Array ( [images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [source] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/67hxjjso2jp21.jpg?auto=webp&s=a2fdef5affa8c53c42afb264a453bd55b8018478 [width] => 1124 [height] => 953 ) [resolutions] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/67hxjjso2jp21.jpg?width=108&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=a0fb39acc8ed464b0435828290df3ed59b59feef [width] => 108 [height] => 91 ) [1] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/67hxjjso2jp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=db2009c47f94c1c6f48d5fd78f0c0c094abf4288 [width] => 216 [height] => 183 ) [2] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/67hxjjso2jp21.jpg?width=320&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=1fda8cd2bb303ae4bfea35f8b914d80f3f6e5063 [width] => 320 [height] => 271 ) [3] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/67hxjjso2jp21.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=9f2dcd2cfb099d0edcdb1f610176a16fc37ec606 [width] => 640 [height] => 542 ) [4] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/67hxjjso2jp21.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=48d089c6f0fac9cbae424b2477af405d48048d2f [width] => 960 [height] => 813 ) [5] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/67hxjjso2jp21.jpg?width=1080&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=a035c5399a6ccfcc7b9b1c63a31f02e56f289dff [width] => 1080 [height] => 915 ) ) [variants] => Array ( ) [id] => pdhs1xe0hSYglI0iivKvpL2WXEBWM6-tlf-E8KMCPrU ) ) [enabled] => 1 ) [media_only] => [can_gild] => [spoiler] => [locked] => [author_flair_text] => [visited] => [num_reports] => [distinguished] => [subreddit_id] => t5_3hmzi [mod_reason_by] => [removal_reason] => [link_flair_background_color] => [id] => b7tgk3 [is_robot_indexable] => 1 [report_reasons] => [author] => Emelito888 [num_crossposts] => 0 [num_comments] => 40 [send_replies] => 1 [whitelist_status] => house_only [mod_reports] => Array ( ) [author_patreon_flair] => [author_flair_text_color] => [permalink] => /r/creepyasterisks/comments/b7tgk3/something_that_i_thought_my_friend_would_never_do/ [parent_whitelist_status] => house_only [stickied] => [url] => https://i.redd.it/67hxjjso2jp21.jpg [subreddit_subscribers] => 346546 [created_utc] => 1554070070 [media] => [is_video] => ) ) [4] => Array ( [kind] => t3 [data] => Array ( [approved_at_utc] => [subreddit] => creepyasterisks [selftext] => [author_fullname] => t2_35un3il5 [saved] => [mod_reason_title] => [gilded] => 0 [clicked] => [title] => ..I just wanted to eat my chicken nuggets in peace.. [link_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [subreddit_name_prefixed] => r/creepyasterisks [hidden] => [pwls] => 1 [link_flair_css_class] => [downs] => 0 [thumbnail_height] => 140 [hide_score] => [name] => t3_b7qpo2 [quarantine] => [link_flair_text_color] => dark [author_flair_background_color] => [subreddit_type] => public [ups] => 5495 [domain] => i.redd.it [media_embed] => Array ( ) [thumbnail_width] => 140 [author_flair_template_id] => [is_original_content] => [user_reports] => Array ( ) [secure_media] => [is_reddit_media_domain] => 1 [is_meta] => [category] => [secure_media_embed] => Array ( ) [link_flair_text] => [can_mod_post] => [score] => 5495 [approved_by] => [thumbnail] => https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/bJ6Wkgoj3wRTY70hrRZu2LlDGxCO6teth0ybVNttnRo.jpg [edited] => [author_flair_css_class] => [author_flair_richtext] => Array ( ) [gildings] => Array ( [gid_1] => 0 [gid_2] => 0 [gid_3] => 0 ) [post_hint] => image [content_categories] => [is_self] => [mod_note] => [created] => 1554055804 [link_flair_type] => text [wls] => 1 [banned_by] => [author_flair_type] => text [contest_mode] => [selftext_html] => [likes] => [suggested_sort] => confidence [banned_at_utc] => [view_count] => [archived] => [no_follow] => [is_crosspostable] => [pinned] => [over_18] => [preview] => Array ( [images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [source] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/pvloz4h9whp21.jpg?auto=webp&s=648c6bcb23d23d714943d3a258d6a8845ebac4c6 [width] => 720 [height] => 1280 ) [resolutions] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/pvloz4h9whp21.jpg?width=108&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=464bc243df124b1e6c4a9be3f972d21d0e9645cb [width] => 108 [height] => 192 ) [1] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/pvloz4h9whp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=983c6b25740ed0389f8077e25d9ade75ae967b81 [width] => 216 [height] => 384 ) [2] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/pvloz4h9whp21.jpg?width=320&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=93d3c388d017af4277cebbe8db5f80d37101a99a [width] => 320 [height] => 568 ) [3] => Array ( [url] => https://preview.redd.it/pvloz4h9whp21.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=fdb547734bd6373b3efe5e395888d0e0f6101f03 [width] => 640 [height] => 1137 ) ) [variants] => Array ( ) [id] => twx13jnh_8HGZz7jbYA4ntFLYVING2fTld5MGTzig6U ) ) [enabled] => 1 ) [media_only] => [can_gild] => [spoiler] => [locked] => [author_flair_text] => [visited] => [num_reports] => [distinguished] => [subreddit_id] => t5_3hmzi [mod_reason_by] => [removal_reason] => [link_flair_background_color] => [id] => b7qpo2 [is_robot_indexable] => 1 [report_reasons] => [author] => PastaDoota_PonkWurm [num_crossposts] => 0 [num_comments] => 171 [send_replies] => 1 [whitelist_status] => house_only [mod_reports] => Array ( ) [author_patreon_flair] => [author_flair_text_color] => [permalink] => /r/creepyasterisks/comments/b7qpo2/i_just_wanted_to_eat_my_chicken_nuggets_in_peace/ [parent_whitelist_status] => house_only [stickied] => [url] => https://i.redd.it/pvloz4h9whp21.jpg [subreddit_subscribers] => 346546 [created_utc] => 1554055804 [media] => [is_video] => ) ) )
```

Comment: Try printing out { $out[0] } and comparing it to what you think it's supposed to be. If all else fails, try doing: { $url = $out[0]; $image = file_get_contents($url); }

Comment: before you try to get image with the array put the line of code `var_export($out);` and edit your question and add the output from `var_export($out);`

Comment: @UncaAlby I've already tried both of these. When I echoed $out[0] and literally copypasted it into file_get_contents it worked. I've also tried setting it as another variable.

Comment: @Jimmix After adding that into code I always get this: https://ctrlv.cz/9HJm

Comment: @JakubHarabiš Why in the world are you hacking at the json string with `substr($post, 1, -1);`  This is a major redflag for me.  As are all of those `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` calls -- none of those should be necessary.  Show us `$post` before you start manipulating it.  `var_export($posts);`

Comment: @mickmackusa I know, that it it really dumb way to get into it, I was trying to decode it myself, but the $post is mix of arrays and objects. I'll add it into original post. That's probably whole problem...

Comment: If the api is delivering urls without html entities encoded, then the urls are html encoded after you "process" the data, then clearly your string manipulations are to blame.  Rather than to add another string manipulation, better programming practices would suggest that you investigate the earliest point of breakage and remove all unnecessary actions.

Comment: When you want to post array data on Stackoverflow so that volunteers can use it, generate the display data with `var_export()` -- `print_r()` means volunteers will have to overhaul the format before being able to use it in their test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have understand your problem.
Its the code **amp;** in the url which is a problem

Try this code

```
<?php
$out = [
    0=>'https://preview.redd.it/jl9xhifkbjp21.jpg?width=216&amp;crop=smart&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=d39e483499249c3863941b4355f37ebff24d4c05',
    1=>'https://preview.redd.it/ak1dcvubgjp21.jpg?width=216&amp;crop=smart&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=aa7f553643a8b0096d0a6d22a3e1440054955d11',
    2=>'https://preview.redd.it/dzx1483qbjp21.jpg?width=216&amp;crop=smart&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=bd53992f74a2a26a89e871e146338a9f4c7a446f',
];

$formateOut = str_replace("amp;", "", $out[0]);

$image = file_get_contents($formateOut);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $image; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$out = [
    0=>"https://preview.redd.it/pvloz4h9whp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=983c6b25740ed0389f8077e25d9ade75ae967b81",
    1=>"https://preview.redd.it/15syi021vhp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=b2bff216f7164084026ad25a11bc4a07f8f88e32",
    2=>"https://preview.redd.it/rz8xy4csrhp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=8a1b4d5ac04958399a184dcbc2045bcb33b559a1",
];

$image = file_get_contents($out[0]);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $image; 
?>
```

Comment: The {0=>} {1=>} and {2=>} should not be necessary, as those are the default keys. Otherwise, there's nothing different from what the OP is doing.

Comment: Yes i know but its for your example ;)

Comment: Oh, Your array works. My array $out is from Reddits JSON API. I just push URLs from API into it. I'm starting to think, that it is some kind of maybe coding/character parsing error? It seems like when URLs are hardcoded, they work, but when they are directly from API they don't work...

Comment: This API return this array ?:

Array ( 
[0] => https://preview.redd.it/pvloz4h9whp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=983c6b25740ed0389f8077e25d9ade75ae967b81 
[1] => https://preview.redd.it/15syi021vhp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=b2bff216f7164084026ad25a11bc4a07f8f88e32 
[2] => https://preview.redd.it/rz8xy4csrhp21.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=8a1b4d5ac04958399a184dcbc2045bcb33b559a1 
)

Comment: You have the link of your JSON API so that I see the problem ?

Comment: I've added code getting data from API into main post.

Comment: "Try this" answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering thousands of future researchers.